# Lodash get uniq objects but return `true` on one property if one of it contains true

Tags: javascript, lodash

Lodash - Return uniq values on array of objects containing `id` and `required`. The uniq should be on `id` and when `required` is true on any one of the object, set required to true on the returned uniq object in the array

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "required": true
},
{
  "id": 1,
  "required": true
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "required": false
},
{
   "id": 3,
   "required": true
},
{
  "id": 4,
   "required": false
},
{
  "id": 4,
   "required": false
}]
```

The final result should be

```
[{
  "id": 1,
  "required": true
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "required": true
},
{
  "id": 4,
   "required": false
}]
```

Comment: Show us where you're struggling with this please so that we can help.

Comment: My question is, is there a lodash function that can do this comparision and return uniq values? Just doing _.uniqBy([arrayOfObject], 'id'); just returns uniq on id.